# Using WCF Client without installing .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-client

I have a WCF Service built with .NET Framework 3.5. I have a task to develop a WCF Client which only uses .NET Framework 2.0. The WCF Client will receive messages which is broadcasted from WCF Service. Can I do this?

The WCF Client runs well on a computer has .NET Framework 3.5. However on a computer which only has .NET Framework 2.0, and including WCF's DLLs in application's folder, WCF Client only send message to service ok but can't receive message from WCF Service.

> WCF Client  ---> WCF Service : OK
>
> WCF Client  <--- WCF Service : Not OK

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service exposes a `basicHttpBinding` endpoint, then you should be able to consume it in a .NET 2.0 application by using "Add Web Reference".

Comment: But I use WCF for bi-directional purpose. I don't like users must install .net framework 3.5 when they use my application because framework's size is big. I need a alternative of WCF. Anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Lu Lu: if you need WCF bidirectional features, then you **need** to have WCF installed, which means you **must have** at least .NET framework 3.0 installed - no way around that.

Comment: I wonder if you can use the Client Profile of the framework? It is a smaller download.

Comment: It looks like the .NET 3.5 Client Profile does include the WCF Client code. Give it a try - it may be small enough for you.